# Trying to lint javascript code with non-ascii character

Tags: jslint

EDIT: *For those that say: do not do this, I most respectfully point out that 1. this is something that is allowed by javascript and, more importantly, 2. this is something that I need to do for pedagogical reasons.*

I would like to "validate" my javascript code with jslint (or jshint ... or something equivalent) but, unfortunately, it fails due to the presence of non-ascii characters in identifiers.  Does someone know of a validator like jslint which accepts non-ascii characters in identifiers?

I know of a partial workaround, which is to use something like

```
this["andré"]
```

instead of

```
this.andré
```

but do not know of an equivalent workaround for something like

```
var andré = ...
```

Comment: Why would you have non-ASCII characters in identifiers to begin with? What if the maintainer doesn't know how to read them (let alone type them)? The linter is complaining for a very good reason. Fix it.

Comment: Pedagogy is about teaching, is it not? You should be teaching/learning good practice.

Comment: Pedagogy implies good communication.  When writing an application that exposes javascript function to the user as a pedagogical tool (but hides much of the complexity of javascript), it makes sense to use function names that can be understood by those users - even those that do not speak English.  Fortunately, the designers of javascript were smart enough to make this possible.  And, based on my 20+ years experience in teaching, I have concluded that it made sense to make use of this capability.  As for good practice: I'm trying to do this myself by using tools like jslint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 1.0.0 of JSHint will add support for unicode characters in identifiers. Currently this is available as a release candidate which you can [download on GitHub](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/tags). From the [JSHint blog](http://www.jshint.com/blog/2012-12-29/1-0-0-rc1/):

> This version **adds support for Unicode identifiers**!
>
> ```
>    var π = 3.1415;
> ```